# How can I continue to solve this PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

I´m having trouble finding the solution of this PDE
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\, \partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$
on $-\infty < x < \infty$, $t>0$, and initial condition $u(x,0)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-|x|}.$

I'm trying to use Fourier Transform and getting to:
$$\tilde{u}(k,t)=\tilde{u}(x,0)e^{ikt}$$

But I'm having trouble to use the inverse Fourier Transform.
I tried making the Fourier Transform $\tilde{u}(k,0)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u(x,0)e^{-ikx}dx$, but could not get to anywhere.

Comment: Title: "continu"? I found [this link](https://www.continu.com).

Comment: You can use substitution $v(x,t) := \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} (x,t)$. This function satisfies the transport equation
$$
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}.
$$

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hint: the fourier transform turns translation by $c$ into multiplication by $e^{ict}$, which you can prove by a direct change of variables in the definition of the Fourier transform.

Comment: Define $v = u_x$ then $v$ satisfies a simple transport equation.